# Python re.findall (returns a number)[0]

Tags: python

I'm trying to teach myself a little python and in the process I'm 'borrowing' code from places to help build my project.  A snipit from a piece of code I have which extracts a temperature value from a string looks like this...

```
re.findall(r"Temp=(\d+.\d+)", *string_variable*)[0]
```

for the life of me, I cannot find any documentation on what the "[0]" is used for at the end and how to use it.

Obviously I figured out that without it my final output is something like this:
['71.8']
and with it, my number is cleaner and rounded up:
72.0

Can someone point me to where this is documented so I can better understand how to use it in the future?

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list. `[]` returns an element (or elements) of that list. `[0]` is the first element.

Answer (score 3):

`re.findall(r"Temp=(\d+.\d+)", string_variable)` returns a list, `[0]` gets the first element of that list.

This is a sign that your method of teaching yourself by looking at snippets of code without context is not working. Go through a more traditional tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation for re](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) in the section `re.findall` states "Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings." So the return value is a list. [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) section on lists explains what `[0]` at the end of the list does.

I highly recommend that you read through the entire [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html), as I did, or something similar, to learn Python.